# Derivative of the greatest integer function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I believe that the derivative of $f(x) = [x]$ with respect to $x$ equals $0$. If so, why does the integral of $0$ does not give $[x]$?

Comment: in general, the indefinite integral of a function derivative is not equal to that function, it's equal to that function plus some constant

Comment: Are you aware of Dirac delta functions?

Comment: @MathLover the Dirac delta function is not a function. It is a generalized function, what is a different thing.

Comment: I dont know who is downvoting this but this is a really very good question. Many people that took some calculus course doesnt know the formal definition of the fundamental theorem of calculus so this question makes complete sense. Indeed indefinite integrals could be defined for discontinuous functions also, but then we need to separate the concept of indefinite integral and anti-derivative.

Comment: @Masacroso: I didn't downvote it, but I would've. I can't speak for other people, but in my opinion, the "I believe ..." part deserves that. It may be just a figure of speech, but still -- this is a math site, not a religious site (sorry, no offense to anyone), so we should rather think and justify our claims. Even mathematicians who say "I believe $P\neq NP$" (as a random example) don't express that as a blind belief, but have a whole lot of evidence to justify why they're inclined to think so. I'm sure the OP has his reasons, but he should've stated them.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $f(x):=\lfloor x\rfloor$ is defined in all the points but the integers, and it equal zero. At the integers the derivative of $f$ doesnt exists.

You are asking why then the indefinite integral of the zero function doesnt return $f$. The case is that indefinite integrals, in general, are understood as anti-derivatives, and an anti-derivative is only defined as a continuous function but our $f$ is not a continuous function so it cannot be an antiderivative.

Comment: Small nitpick:  in your notation, the greatest integer function is usually written $x \mapsto \lfloor x \rfloor$ (as in the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$, the floor function).  $x \mapsto \lceil x \rceil$ is the least integer function

Comment: @Xander I thought it is the greatest near integer. The greatest near integer of $1/2$ is $2$... Maybe this is to me cause Im not english-speaker.